# In Matplotlib, is there a way to have mixed float and integer values for an axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a Weibull log-log plot and my values on the x-axis are from 0 to 100. If In my code if put `%.i` the values between 0 and 1 are all displayed as 0. If I put `%.1f` the values above 1 all have one decimal place and at about 70.0 they start to overlap all the way to 100.

In my code I am using `plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_formatter((FormatStrFormatter("%.i")))` to format to have ingtegers only.

I need to have values like this:
0, 0.1, 0.2, ... 0.9, 10^1, 2, 3, ..., 99, 10^2 on the x axis.

The plotting function is part of a much bigger function that could accept any numbers for the x-axis. There is normally no issue if values happen to be higher than 1. However, being part of a function I need it to be able to self-format for values bellow 1 (exclusive) as floats and integer for the remaining points.

This is what I get with integers only:
[image: integers only]

This is what I get with floats only:
[image: floats only]

How could I mix these two?

Comment: First you could create a list of strings containing the desired xtick_labels. Then apply them using set_xticklabels.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the idea Fank Tap. I did not implement it as is but it made me go into a different direction. I defined the possibilities for the axis in a list and used it instead.

```
xtickvals = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]
```

and then I used:

```
plt.xticks(xtickvals)
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(['{:}'.format(x) for x in xtickvals])
```

The final result is as I needed it to be:
[image]